# Запрос sqlite3

Tags: sqlite3

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста кто знает, почему не работает такой код:

```
$db = new SQLite3("KOnATbl4.sqlite");
$db->exec('CREATE TABLE base (name STRING, city STRING, home INTEGER)');
$db->exec("INSERT INTO base VALUES ('John', 'Moscow', 12)");
$results = $db->query("SELECT name, city, home FROM base");
```

В БД ничего не добавляется... И дальнейший код(по работе с полученными данными) не работает... Добавлял данные в ручную через SQlite Manager, всё работало..

Comment: Потому что вы создаете/делаете выборку из таблицы base, а добавляете в top?

Comment: Нет:-) Это я исправлял, и не доисправил...

Comment: И кстати снова здравствуйте Fike

Comment: Я думал что возможно причина в том что БД не имеет нужные права доступа(для записи), но и не в этом дело...

Comment: commit разве на php после записи не нужен?

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу, вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением, а когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в используемом расширением синтаксисе. Возвращаются не сами данные, а объект [SQLite3Result](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.sqlite3result.php), который предполагает следующее обращение:

```
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
    var_dump($row); // вот здесь-то данные и лежат
}
```

А если вардампнуть его, то и вправду складывается впечатление, что он пустой.

Comment: Вы меня не поняли.... Я скинул код который не делает того что должен... То что я скинул должно создавать БД и добавлять данные в таблицу. Этого не происходит. А вообще весь код выглядит вот так:  
$db = new SQLite3("KOnATbl4.sqlite");
$db->exec('CREATE TABLE base (name STRING, city STRING, home INTEGER)');// 
$db->exec("INSERT INTO base VALUES ('John', 'Moscow', 12)");
$results = $db->query("SELECT name, city, home FROM base");
            $p = 0; 
            while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {   
      $p += $row['home']*3;
            echo $p;                 
     }

Comment: @istimbi, сам файл БД создается?

Comment: Нет... И я не понимаю почему:-(

Comment: Есть ли у пользователя, выполняющего пхп-код, права на папку? И лучше указать абсолютный путь, конечно.

Comment: Fike, Я ступил:-), точнее я не знал (по причине недостатка опыта) что нужно ставить права записи ещё и на папку... Спасибо за помошь.